# how to check if UIScrollView content doesn't need to use scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

My problem is I need to change the label text color below my scroll view if the content of my scroll view is not all visible.

**For example:** I have a label colored red, if all the content of the scroll view can be seen on the screen(not using scroll at all), and the label colored blue if all the content inside of my scroll view is not visible. how to do it programmatically?

**NOTE: I have a contentView -> scrollView (programmatically) -> stackView (programmatically).
(stackview inside scrollview and scrollview inside contentview. and a label below the content view)**

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are dynamically adding elements to your scroll view (such as a variable number of buttons), you can compare the `scrollView.contentSize.height` to `scrollView.frame.size.height` ... but ***only after*** auto-layout has done its work. so when (in your code) are you adding elements and wanting to check for scroll need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Get the height of the content view of scrollView

```
let totalHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
```

2: In viewDidLoad check:

```
if totalHeight > scrollView.frame.size.height { 
    // can scroll more 
} else { 
   // full content visible
}
```

3: once user starts scrolling, you can call:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        //reached to bottom
    } else {
        // can scroll more
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't work :< and i think i said it wrong, my scroll view have buttons -> buttons may be 4 or many, if 4 i dont have to scroll to see all, but more for example 7 to 30, i have to scroll. and i need to change the label colored depends on, if my scrollview needs to scroll or not. thank you

Comment: you also need to set `scrollVIew.delegate = self` and `class ViewController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me, with the difference that I placed it in the **viewDidAppear**

```
if scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.visibleSize.height {
    // can scroll more
} else {
   // full content visible
}
```